# IOS Membership tax file Query

Tags: iphone

I am located in Australia and would like to post my app on app store so that the whole world can take advantage of it. I have filled out the ABN and GST details for only Australia and I am not sure if this is all we need to do to get the app available on the world scale.

Please answer my query, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you planning on selling the app? If so, then you need to fill out all of the necessary forms iTunes Connect will let you know what steps you need to take in order to start selling your app and start receiving profits from those sales.

If you plan on offering your app for FREE, then there are no tax forms you need to fill out.

Comment: yes i wanna sell it, so if the app goes in to australian app store, will the users from other countries get the chance to download it aswell?

Comment: Yes, your app will be available world-wide.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is all you need. When you upload your app you can specify which stores it will be available in. By the way, this is not a programming related question.